# Taking over the lead of a team but not official - am I not set up for success?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, manager, team

I joined a software development team at work 12 months ago, switching from a different team within the same company. Let's briefly go through the people in the team: a manager and then myself, person A, person B, myself and 2 trainees (all Java devs).

When I joined it was pretty clear that person A is the lead of the team, even if it was never really official. But every large code change/architecture update/planning involves person A. Team members speak highly of A. So no question A is a good choice.

Now A will leave the company in a few months, this is official. Our manager is asking me to take over A's responsibilities and step forward to drive the team. For me it makes sense, since I've been 10 years with the company in total, have the most overall development experience from the team and had previous experience in such roles. The manager mentions if I "do well, this will help with a promotion."

However, I think person B in the team has also probably interest to take the lead. I notice that B is not very keen on doing stuff with me in general: short if any replies if I include them on something (like message via email or chat), almost never they include me on stuff they do unless it's basically mandated by the manager, neutral or dismissive attitude to my suggestions (usually short replies like: "probably won't work, but okay ..."). B's clearly more active since it's clear A is leaving. I tried to be open to B's ideas, but usually I get the feeling that they expect that their ideas are superior (hence I'm supposed to be open to their ideas) and thus don't reciprocate that much. I also overheard B is lamenting A's upcoming departure, since then it's difficult to plan future tasks properly without A.

All in all what irks me is to some extend B's behaviour, but what I see problematic is that there seems to be no official announcement planned as to who is leading soon (as A was never officially leading the project either) and I think that this will lead to more conflicts, since both me and B will see themselves in the same role.

Is it now bad attitude from myself to insist that the manager makes my future roles clear to the team? Or should I go along here and just see how it plays out and I just need to "prove myself"? Eventually it also worked for A, apparently. But I don't want to be in a situation where the manager has two horses in the race and the one that does better in 12 months gets a promotion. Not so keen on these kind of in-team competition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it now bad attitude from myself to insist that the manager makes my
> future roles clear to the team?

It would be a mistake to think you can insist. You aren't really in a position to insist on anything.

Instead, explain what you see happening and ask for advice from your manager. Probe to see if your manager thinks that making an announcement now makes sense or not. But don't insist.

Eventually, you will need to learn how to deal with conflict on your own - leaders encounter conflict all the time.

> But I don't want to be in a situation where the manager has two horses
> in the race and the one that does better in 12 months gets a
> promotion. Not so keen on these kind of in-team competition.

After talking with your manager, if you think you are in a competition and you aren't willing to compete, you can decline the leadership role, or choose to find a new job and leave this one.

Comment: Fair points, I'd agree it basically boils down to how the manager wants to see it and thus handle (or not handle) it.

Comment: Maybe one question to you, how does one learn to handle situations like this without getting too attached to it? Like, I've been thinking already a long time back and forth about future possible conflicts and how I might handle them in this situation ... pretty useless and starts to affect my personal well-being. Just put yourself in these situations and deal with it (or fail) and survival of the fittest? (Pretty open ended Q, but general guidance is already useful.)